# How to run .NET 4 code analysis on build server

Tags: .net-4.0, fxcop, build-server

On a Windows Server 2003 R2 with .NET 4 SDK but without Visual Studio 2010, I have tried building a Visual Studio 2010 solution with

```
msbuild MySolution.sln /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true
```

but that fails.

What is required to run code analysis on such an environment?

---

I get this error message:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets(129,9): error MSB6003: 
The specified task executable "FxCopCmd.exe" could not be run. 
Could not load file or assembly 
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.Sdk, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken= b03f5f7f11d50a3a' 
or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have installed FxCop from the SDK and without luck pointed the variable FxCopDir to the installed location of FxCopCmd.exe, and also setting this registry entry to that location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Setup\EDev@FxCopDir
```

Comment: This works for C++ project, but not C# project

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem on my MSBuild server and fixed it by:

- Installing **Windows SDK 7.1**
- Setting up the registry keys **FxCopDir** and **StanDir** in    **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Setup\EDev** (in Win32).

I then copied over from the dev PC, to the **FxCop** folder on the build server, the following:

- The folder **Rule Sets** (default installation target is here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop)
- **Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.Sdk.dll**
- **Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.Phoenix.dll**
- **phx.dll**

Do a search for them on your dev PC with Visual Studio installed to locate them.

Then use the .NET 4.0 version of **gacutil.exe** to install **Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.Sdk.dll** to the GAC.

You *should* then be able to run code analysis as part of an MSBuild build and have it work properly.

Comment: Thanks! Including these assemblies and rules made it work for me.

Comment: What value should be set to StanDir?

Comment: if it worked for somebody with .NET 4.5 and projects built in VS 2012, could you share the step-by-step instructions?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to FxCop would be to use the tool NDepend that lets write [Code Rules over C# LINQ Queries (namely CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL). *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

More than [200 code rules](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html) are proposed by default. Customizing existing rules or creating your own rules is straightforward thanks to the *well-known* C# LINQ syntax.

Rules can be verified [live in Visual Studio](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_CQL.aspx) and at Build Process time, in a [generated HTML+javascript report](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule).

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be calling FxCop executable as a build task (from [msbuildtasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/)), saving the result as an XML file that can be parsed within most of the CI tools (like Hudson and CC.NET)